# Compile & Build error related to "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'"

Tags: ios, swift

I am not understanding why my app is not compiling. This is the output currently:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var IndexArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsinTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return IndexArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, tiltleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return IndexArray[section]
    }

    func sectionIndexTitlesfortableView (tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return IndexArray
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TableCell

        cell.imgPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "charity")
        cell.lblUserName.text! = "User Name"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

Comment: All of your tableview methods have misspelled/miscapitalized words or are using swift 2 method signatures which are different in swift 3.  Use Xcode's autocomplete to get the correct signatures.

Comment: What Swift version are you talking about? The code is a Swift 2 / 3 mingle-mangle.

Comment: I believe I am using Swift version 3. I am unsure how to determine the Swift version.

Comment: Then comment out all table view delegate methods and retype them to use code completion. They are pretty much different in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to specify a few methods declared in the protocols your class is deriving from.

func tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath)
Required. Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.

func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)
Required. Tells the data source to return the number of rows in a given section of a table view.

At least the two methods above must be declared in your class, otherwise you get the error.

These are just the required methods, but for functioning in the correct way you need to define others. See Apple documentation on UITableViewDataSource protocol

Comment: In the video I was watching, the code above was all that was included and he app was able to launch successfully. What should the code be changed to for the app to compile successfully?

Comment: Maybe the video was made for an older iOS version... difficult to say. Implement the functions marked as required for the protocols you decide to add and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 all method signatures have been changed to:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? { }

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? { }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```